# Laravel - two foreign keys in belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel

I know there are similar questions but I didn't find the answer.

I have two tables

```
users:
    id
    name

chats:
    id
    user_id
    friend_id
```

and I need to get `friends` from Chat model.
So, if `Auth::id() === chats.user_id` I need a user with friend_id as fk

I was trying something like this, but didn't work

```
public function userOne() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
}

public function userTwo() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'friend_id');
}

public function friend() {
    if ($this->userOne()->first()->id === Auth::user()->id) {
        return $this->userTwo();
    }

    return $this->userOne();
}
```

So, basically I need condition in Chat model to check if `id` isn't mine and then return a `friend`, or different relationship?

Comment: You are looking for something like ->hasMany('App\Friend') on your User model.

Answer (score 0):

Look what you are doing. Let us have a user with **id = 1**. Then when you call the method **$user->userOne()**, all columns from the chats table are selected where **user_id = 1**. When you call **$user->userTwo()**, then from the table of chats, all **friend_id = 1** will be dragged out.
Now we call the **$user->friend()** that will take place

```
     if ($user->userOne()->first()->id === Auth::user()->id) {
         return $this->userTwo();
     }
```

i.e.

```
     if (id of our user == 1) {
        then return all columns where friend_id = 1
     }
```

You need that

```
if ($this->userOne()->first()->user_id === Auth::user()->id) {
         return $this->userOne()->first()->friend_id;
}
```

Comment: `userOne()` returns user model, so it doesn't have `user_id`. Anyway, I solve a problem with query builder...

Answer (score 0):

Friend can be a method of User

in your Friend model add

```
public function friend()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Friend');
}
```